# What is the best way to pass strongly typed variables to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, strongly-typed-view

Is there any way that I can pass **multiple** variables to a view so I can work with the type members and methods?

I want to be more safe with my coding? `ViewData` will not pass strongly typed.

ASP.net 4 MVC 3
Thanks

Comment: What framework are you using here? ASP.NET MVC? or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the way to do this is to create a view-model that has the various values you need, i.e.

```
public class SomeSpecificViewModel {
    public int SomeValue {get;set;}
    public string AnotherValue {get;set;}
    public FancyType MoreComplexValue {get;set;}
}
```

Now pass a `SomeSpecificViewModel` to the view, and tell your view to expect a `SomeSpecificViewModel`. Then just access the members.

Comment: Do I need to declare on it in the view? if so, how?

Comment: @yos if this is razor, then at the top: `@model SomeSpecificViewModel` - job done; when you access `Model.blah`, you'll notice that `Model` ***is*** a `SomeSpecificViewModel`